# Facebook Login for browser extension running on www.facebook.com

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I know Facebook Login is a big topic and there are a lot of questions already asked, but I couldn't find the right answer for my specific problem.

I wanna use the Facebook Login to get a User Access Token to use the Facebook Graph API. All that should work in javascript that is loaded into the Facebook page. I just want the user to login to my app (to get his permission), but there should be no redirect.

> Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.

Of course I understand the problem, but I have no URL to point it to and facebook won't let me enter their URL (https://www.facebook.com). There is no domain I could enter. The process should go like this:

User clicks button on a div on the facebook page -> login popup for my app -> popup closes, user sees facebook again and I received the access token

This is the code for the login call, just for test function right now:

```
FB.login(function(response) { alert(response.authResponse.accessToken);
    });
```

This is getting executed after the user clicks a button, while being on Facebook.

Comment: what button on a div on the facebook page? where do you put your code, if you don´t even have any server/url?

Comment: I add the javascript code into the facebook page via a browser extension I add script tags holding the code and then load it from gitHub, but I could also just have it as inline script code. That code renders the div button and so on

Comment: What purpose is this supposed to serve? What is your app supposed to do, that it has to be running “on” Facebook this way? // I don’t think there is any other way to get this to work, than to place this on an external domain, implementing the standard web login there - and then have your browser extension load & display the content from that domain somewhere.

Comment: Hmm okay...thanks!